# threejs: how to set renderer size to fit screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

Using code below I have some problems:

```
        //WebGL renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); //TODO: set optimal size   
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Top left corner - some thin white border:

[image]

Bottom right corner - scroll elements (looks like `window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight` is bigger then initial view):

[image]

How to get w,h for `renderer.setSize` to fit all visible area inside window? Or maybe this problems should be fixed in other way?

Comment: I assume you want your renderer to be full screen and you don't have anything else on the page. If that's the case, all you need is `overflow:hidden` on `<body>`. If you want to have vertical scroll, use `overflow-x:hidden;`. You're correct in using `window.innerWidth`, as on devices which do not have permanent scrollbars your renderer would be narrower if you try to factor in the width of scrollbar on traditional desktops (`17px`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the white space at the top and left is because I think the body has a margin by default.
The scrollbars are because for reasons unknown to me, the canvas element behaves as if it is an inline element.

This css should fix it:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It works. Looks like `body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}` is sufficient, is `canvas {
  display: block;
}` necessary?

Comment: I would reverse this. With `canvas { display: block; }` is the `overflow: hidden;` needed?